# H2O python: gbm predictions uncertainty

Tags: python-3.x, prediction, h2o, gbm, uncertainty

I am new to h2o in python. I'm fitting a GBM with cross-validation on my training set and then get predictions on a holdout set. My outcome is CONTINOUOUS and for every prediction I would like to have a measure of uncertainty.  I'm not interested in prediction intervals, I simply look for an uncertainty score for every prediction that I make. Any ideas are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you doing classification? when you use .predict() it will give you the classification and predicted probabilities (note these are not calibrated probabilities, to get the calibrated probabilities you need to do a few more steps using h2o's calibrated frame.

Comment: I'd recommend editing your question to clarify what you mean by "uncertainties" -- raw predicted values or calibrated predicted probabilities.  Confidence intervals are not available, though I don't think that's what you're referring to.

Comment: thank you for your responses, I've edited my post. I'm actually doing regression and need an uncertainty score for every prediction that I make.

Comment: @ErinLeDell is it possible to obtain probabilities of predictions for regression tasks (for GBM)? Could you explain shortly the possible ways of getting calibrated probabilities?

Comment: Yes, H2O offers Platt scaling in GBM and RFs to yield calibrated probabilities.  More info here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/calibrate_model.html